# django custom command not found

Tags: django

Having issues getting django custom commands to work.

From django [documetation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), have placed

```
application/
    manage.py
    blog/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        management/
            __init__.py
            commands/
                __init__.py
                myapp_task.py
        views.py
```

myapp_task.py content is

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        print 'Doing task...'
        # invoke the functions you need to run on your project here
        print 'Done'
```

when ran

```
python manage.py myapp_task
```

getting error

```
Unknown command: 'myapp_task'
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The directory structure in your answer is a little ambiguous; when placing the files as follows django should be able to find your command:

```
project/ # in your question this would be 'application'
    manage.py
    blog/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        management/
            __init__.py
            commands/
                __init__.py
                myapp_task.py
        views.py
```

Furthermore, you'll need to enable your app in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'blog', # <= your app here ...
)
```

Comment: the file structure is correct, just got messed up pasting it here

Comment: it is listed in installed apps in settings

Comment: The indenting of the file list is still off.

Comment: helped me, i was missing __init__.py in my management/ directory.

Comment: Adding it to the settings.py did it for me (not in the Django documentation). Also, __init__.py is only needed if you're using Python 2.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not enable the app

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The reason was that the project root was not in my $PYTHONPATH. The solution in this case is to type (on a Linux machine) something like

```
PYTHONPATH=./project python manage.py myapp_task
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was I was adding the management directory in my main app besides my settings.py file  once I have added it to another app it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I had cut and paste the filename from an example and had paste a space at the start of the filename. Therefore Django could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think commands/ needs to be inside the management/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is byte-compiled, django.core.management.find_commands() will only look for .py files. If your custom commands are in .pyc files, you need to patch django/core/management/commands/__init__.py with the patch at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19085

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also had this problem and found out I was mixing up the argument identifier with the file name

so the file is the name of the command you want i.e. `updater` I changed **updatefiles.py** to **updater.py**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Update Files Since \'X\' Days Ago'   

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('updatefiles', nargs='+', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        days_ago = int(options['updatefiles'][0])
        days_ago = (days_ago * -1) if days_ago < 0 else days_ago

        self.stdout.write('Adding files since %s days ago' % days_ago)
        add_files_function(days_ago)
```

then to run I would use

```
python manage.py updater
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this during a refactoring. Running `python manage.py help` listed only core commands, and hinted that something was broken in settings.py.

Answer (score -3):

It is because the **init**.pyc does not get created automatically within "management" and "commands" folder. Copy `your_app/__init__.py` and `your_app/__init__.pyc` and paste it within the management/ and commands/ folder.

Comment: Isn't this a horrible hack? Why would one have to be bothered with whether .pyc's exist? Isn't it python2|3's job to compile, and shouldn't runtime introspection or whatever django-admin does to find commands be invariant to whether .pyc's exist?